# Swift PlaygroundsでNSDataAssetを使用するとエラーが発生する

Tags: swift

iPad(iPadOS 15.2)の**Swift Plygrounds4**で、以下のコードを実行すると、`Cannot find ‘NSDataAsset’ in scope`  というエラーが発生し、再生することができません。
(Appモードでプロジェクトを実行しています。)

```swift
import AVFoundation
   
// 原因だと思われる箇所
let sound = try! AVAudioPlayer(data: NSDataAsset(name: "Sound")!.data)
//
   
func soundplay() {
  sound.prepareToPlay()
  sound.stop()
  sound.currentTime = 0
  sound.play()
}
```

Xcodeではクラッシュは発生しませんでした。
また、`Sound.mp3`  は事前に読み込み済みです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Appモードでプロジェクトを実行しています。* と言うのがどう言う意味なのかがはっきりしないのですが、`Cannot find ‘NSDataAsset’ in scope`と言うエラーが出るのは、「Swiftコンパイラ的には`NSDataAsset`なんてわかりません」と言われてしまっているのです。

これは実行時エラーではなく、ビルド時のエラーです。

`NSDataAsset`を使いたいのであれば、きちんとドキュメントを参照して見てください。

[NSDataAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdataasset)

> ###### Frameworks
>
> UIKit
> AppKit

ドキュメントの`Frameworks`のところにUIKitとAppKitが書いてありますから、このクラスは`UIKit`か`AppKit`かのどちらかに定義されていると言うことです。

適切な`import`を追加して見てください。

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit //<-

//...
```

(これで`Cannot find ‘NSDataAsset’ in scope`のエラーは出なくなるはずですが、あなたのコードがそれで期待通りに動くかどうかはその他の条件によります。)

---

なお、「Xcodeではクラッシュは発生しませんでした。」とありますが、Swift Playgroundsでもビルド時エラーになるだけで *クラッシュ* は発生しませんし、Xcodeでも`import`が同じなら同様に`Cannot find ‘NSDataAsset’ in scope`のエラーが発生します。

補助的な情報を追記される場合には、より具体的にどんなことをどんな環境で試したのか記載されると、もっと複雑な質問をされる場合でも、誤解の余地が減って適切な回答を得やすくなるだろうと思います。

Comment: 確認してみたところ、XcodeではStoryBoardを使用していたため、自動的に`import UIKit`が入力されている状態でした。`NSDataAsset`は使えているようです。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Storyboardを使用しただけで「自動的に`import UIKit`が入力されている」ことにはならないので、何が起こっていたか私的な興味が湧くところですが、とりあえずご質問となった問題点が解決できたのであれば良かったです。

Comment: コメントに誤りがあり、自動的に入力されてはいないようでした。このスプリクトは元々｀ViewController.swift｀に入力していたのですが、ファイルには元々テンプレートとしてimportされていたようです。度々迷惑をお掛けし申し訳ありません。

Comment: 了解しました。わざわざお時間をとって私的な興味にお付き合いいただいてありがとうございます。是非当サイトのようなQAサイトもうまく活用して、良いアプリを作れるようになれるよう願っております。